# How can I add a flag to a URL?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, string-concatenation, flags

I'm setting up a website where visitors will be greeted by a splash screen where they will choose a color scheme for the actual website; based on their selection, the actual website will load with a different stylesheet. I gather this can be done by concatenating a flag to the URL, then reading the flagged URL on the next page to determine the stylesheet to be loaded (for example, to load the dark theme, the url would become `http://www.mywebsite.com/index-dark`; clicking the light theme link would make the URL `http://www.mywebsite.com/index-light`. Problem is, I don't know how to add a flag to a URL, or how to read this flag on a different page. I've tried Googling the issue, but have found little practical information. How can this be done?

EDIT: I'd like to avoid using two separate pages, as I'll have multiple themes; that would mean copying basically every HTML page in my root multiple times, taking up space. I like the idea of a concealed `$_GET` variable, though.

Comment: There are several much better ways of doing this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Unless you hint to what they are, that's not very helpful.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Session, cookies, url: that's all I can think of for an anonymous user - what else did you have in mind that equates to "several"?

Comment: Any downside to just using a cookie/session?

Comment: Still learning how to use cookies and sessions; it'll take longer to develop using them. Otherwise, that would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "flags" you're mentioning are probably actually `$_GET` variables that have been disguised using `mod_rewrite`. What you can do is edit your `.htaccess` file to add in rewrite rules that change, say, `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?style=index-dark` to `www.mywebsite.com/index-dark` (unfortunately I don't have experience in how exactly to do this; I just know that it can be done) and have your PHP catch `$_GET['style']`.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I can only give some general advice.

So I'm going to assume that you are building a page in PHP, so you could have two different urls and use mod_rewrite to convert `/index-dark` to `/index?style=dark` but that's crappy.

What you probably want is to use a cookie or a session. Basically you check a [cookie](http://php.net/cookies), or [session value](http://php.net/sessions), for the theme setting and then pick the appropriate CSS file when you generate the page.

This has several advantages:

- Doesn't require using url rewriting, an error prone endeavour at the best of times
- Allows for persistent setting (if you use a cookie) and doesn't involve complicated urls.
- Allows for adding more themes without changing mountains of code, just add the setting to theme selector and the new CSS file.

GET variables are generally only useful for specific data sent with that request, a bit like POST variables are mostly for forms and submitted data. If you want persistent settings, then a session/cookie is the best option.